# assembler Intel x86 32 bit gas

Tags: assembly, x86, att

i have  a problem with assembler program x86, 32 bit, gas. I would like to code pgcd.

Here the code. When I execute it, it loops forever.

With gdb, i see the instruction `movl $diviseur,dividende` is problematic. But I don't understand why.

I tested my code on Debian 9.

```
        .data
dividende:
        .long  21
diviseur:
        .long 14
mresul:
        .space 8

        .text
        .globl _start

_start:
        movl $dividende,%eax
        movl $diviseur,%ebx
        cdq
        div %ebx
        movl $diviseur,dividende
        movl %edx,diviseur
        cmp $0,%edx
        jnz _start

        movl %ebx,mresul

done:
        movl $0,%ebx
        movl $1,%eax
        int $0x80
```

the result should have been 7

Comment: Storing the address of `$diviseur` into the memory at `dividende` is unlikely to be useful.  Just use registers, that's what they're for.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, thank you for your help. using registers helps me to see errors

Comment: In particular this instruction doesn't do what you think it does: `movl $diviseur,dividende` moves the address of `diviseur` to the memory location `dividende`

Comment: @Michael Petch Thank, your comment was helpful

Comment: Ok, it works.  This code   '.data
dividende:
        .long 13481754
diviseur:
        .long 1234715

        .text
        .globl _start

_start:
        movl dividende,%eax
        movl diviseur,%ebx


boucle: cdq
        div %ebx
        cmp $0,%edx
        jz  aff
        movl %ebx,%eax
        movl %edx,%ebx
        jmp boucle

aff:    movl %ebx,%ecx


done:
        movl $0,%ebx
        movl $1,%eax
        int $0x80
' returns 19. Thanks for your help. It's resolved